# Cant't delete my custom posts

Tags: save-post

I added this code in function.php in order to replace post_date with an ACF field every time i update mu custom post. It works perfectly !

BUT

Now in WP admin i can't delete (to trash) any custom post in the list

Could someone help me please ?
thanks

```
add_action('save_post', 'change_content');

global $post;
global $wpdb;
function change_content($post_id) 
{
    if(get_post_type($post_type) == 'mycustompost' &&  get_field ('dates_0_date_spectacle')     != '' )
    {   
        $datefield = get_post_meta($post_id,'dates_0_date_spectacle',true);
        $post_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($datefield));
        $my_post = array();
        $my_post['ID'] = $post_id;
        $my_post['post_date'] = $post_date;
        $my_post['post_status'] = 'publish';
        remove_action('save_post', 'change_content');
        wp_update_post( $my_post );
        add_action('save_post', 'change_content');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Of course your custom posts can't be trashed. They can't even get set to private or draft or anything else then `publish` because your callback `change_content()` always sets the post status to `publish` every time  a post (of your custom post type) gets saved. However trashing a post just means setting its status to `trash`.

I'm not sure what you want to achieve with this line of code:

```
$my_post['post_status'] = 'publish';
```

but if you want to track status changes you will have to hook into the [`transition_post_status`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/transition_post_status/) hook. Here's a quick, yet untested example on how to do this:

```
namespace WPSE186226;

class TrackPostStatus {

    private $tashedPostsIds = [];

    /**
     * @wp-hook transition_post_status
     * @param string $newStatus
     * @param string $oldStatus
     * @param \WP_Post $post
     */
    public function post_status_transition( $newStatus, $oldStatus, \WP_Post $post ) {

        //e.g. register when a post gets trashed:
        if ( 'trash' !== $old_status && 'trash' === $new_status )
            $this->trashedPostsIds[] = $post->ID;
    }

    /**
     * @wp-hook save_post
     * @param int $postId
     */
    public function handle_post( $postId ) {

        if ( ! in_array( $postId, $this->trashedPostIds ) )
             return;

        // call your logic here. 
    }

}

$postStatusTracker = new TrackPostStatus;
add_action( 'transition_post_status', [ $postStatusTracker, 'post_status_transition' ], 10, 3);
add_action( 'save_post', [ $postStatusTracker, 'handle_post' ] );
```

*Note: this example uses PHP 5.4 syntax and is not compatible to PHP 5.3 or below*

This way provides you a more flexible handling with post status transitions. However there's a simpler hook when you just want to track the new status: [`{$new_status}_{$post_type}`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/new_status_post-post_type/)

Comment: ah ok thanks a lot i understand my code now ;-) so maybe i can suppress $my_post['post_status'] = 'publish'; because i just need to modify post_date...

Comment: You should copy the data from the given post instead of creating new post data.

Comment: sorry David i don't understand...The purpose was to modify post_date and it works like this if i don't modify the post_status

Comment: Never mind, I was mistakenly assume that `wp_update_post()` set non-given fields to an empty value. That's in fact wrong.